# Parsing unique line (using linq)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a file containing likes written like this:

`[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].`

E.g.:

`[Person]: [Age]-[21], [HairColor]-[Turqoise], [Gender]-[Other].`

While I'm familiar with Linq, I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how I would parse this, using Linq.

I'd like to be able to just go over all the lines:

```
[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].
[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].
[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].
[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].
[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].
[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].
[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].
[NAME]: [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE], [PROPERTY]-[VALUE].
```

... And do something with each person retrieved.

Any ideas? Any help at all will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I would like to get all properties/values of a line into an object; and do this for each line in the file.

Comment: Based on your clarification comment you made in your original question, 

> Sorry, yes. I would like to get all properties/values of a line into
> an object; and do this for each line in the file.

You want to parse text from a file into an object.  LINQ will not help you in this case because a LINQ lamba expressions are operations on existing objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, if I've got what you need correctly, of course:

```
        File.ReadAllLines("Utils.txt")
            .Select(s => new
            {
                Name = s.Substring(1, s.IndexOf("]:") - 1),
                Values = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(":") + 2)
                          .Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                          .ToDictionary(l => l.Substring(1, l.IndexOf("]-") - 1),
                                        l => l.Substring(l.IndexOf("-[") + 2).Trim(']'))
            })
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(o =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(o.Name);
                    o.Values.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\t{0}:\t{1}", p.Key, p.Value)));
                });
```

So, here you get a list of anonymous objects with two properties:

1. Name just a string
2. Values - a dictionary of  pairs where a key is your property and a value is your value

In my example I do a simple loop through what I've read, printing it into the console

The content of the test file (Utils.txt) was the following:

```
[NAME]: [PROPERTY1]-[VALUE1], [PROPERTY2]-[VALUE2], [PROPERTY3]-[VALUE3] 
[Person]: [Age]-[21], [HairColor]-[Turqoise], [Gender]-[Other]
```

The output:

```
NAME
    PROPERTY1:  VALUE1
    PROPERTY2:  VALUE2
    PROPERTY3:  VALUE3
Person
    Age:    21
    HairColor:  Turqoise
    Gender: Other
```

Comment: If you had some class (or classes), describing the objects kept in those text lines, it would be possible create strongly-typed objects, not anonymous through Reflection...and the necessity in a Dictionary would disappear

Answer (score 1):

You would not parse it with LINQ. You would parse it with regular expressions or something similar then use LINQ to operate on it.

For example, use a regular expression like:

```
\[(.*)\]: \[(.*)\]-\[(.*)\], \[(.*)\]-\[(.*)\], \[(.*)\]-\[(.*)\]
```

and use the parenthesized groups.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to parse:

```
string input = "[Person]: [Age]-[21], [HairColor]-[Turqoise], [Gender]-[Other].";
var output = input.Split(new[] {':', '-', ','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Trim('[', ']', ' ', '.')).ToList();

var name = output.First();
var properties = output.Skip(1).ToList();

var propertyDic = Enumerable.Range(0, properties.Count()/2)
                         .ToDictionary(i => properties.ElementAt(2*i),
                                       i => properties.ElementAt(2*i + 1));
```